# Stripe - One Click Upsell Possible with stripe.js?

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm making a simple stripe checkout using Leadpages. With that said, I'm only able to use stripe.js rather than all of the massive API features that Stripe has to offer.

After entering the credit card information, the customer will be sent to an upsell page. Is it possible to do a 1-click upsell using Stripe.js?

If not, I may have to look into other options.

Comment: Stripe.js only creates card tokens and nothing else. It doesn't charge the customer so you need some server-side code or a third-party platform for this.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have a PHP file running on the backend here as well. Just have no idea where to start with this. Would ideally like to store the information and offer an upsell. If they hit the next page.

Comment: This really is specific to your integration, if you use LeadPages I'm not even sure that's possible. I'd recommend asking them directly and otherwise potentially stop using LeadPages and build your own integration instead so that you can charge the expected amount at the end

Comment: Thanks again. Do you know which part of Stripe's API can hold a token or whatever needs to be held before completing the charge? Ideally, the flow would be perfect as - "buys first item" - Has option to buy second item [Yes] or [No] buttons. No redirects to thank you page and charges card just that part. Yes charges both parts. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for going out of your way to help out.

Comment: It's nothing to do with Stripe's API here really. You'd save the token in your session for example so that you can offer the second product and then decide to charge for both products if they say yes